# AngularJS-Text box value not found on ng-click of a button under section container

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new in Angular and I am doing a project in **MVC**. I have a section container which is rendered in _layout.cshtml page. Inside the section container there is a button. when I click the button to get value of a textbox, The value get blank. **Here is the code**

```
@section container{
    <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <button ID="btnNext" ng-click="test()"></button>
    </div>
}
<div class="container" ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <input id="txtCode" type="text" ng-model="tst.textbox"/>
</div>
```

**Here is the code in controller**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller("ctrl", ["$scope",
    function ($scope) {
$scope.tst= {};
$scope.tst.textbox='';
$scope.test = function () {
alert($scope.tst.textbox);
//when I give something to textbox for alert it returns nothing
}
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are using the **`same controller`** across two divs, so whenever new controller is set, the existing **`value gets cleared`**.

You should either use different controller, or have a common **`$scope context`** for both input and the button.

if you have two **`different $scope contexts`** then you should use **`service`** to share the variable across the controller.

Comment: that's worked for me. Thanks. Took 2 distinct controller and a factory for passing data between two controllers.